# Show that the image of a zero measure set is of zero measure

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I saw a topic on the subject but I did not quite understand, and it was a bit old and I didn't want to resurrect it.

I am going in the right direction, I just need a little nudge.

let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a smooth function $C^{\infty}$ (meaning $f$ is continuous, differentiable, and the differential of any order is also continuous).

let $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a set of measure zero.

Show that $f(E)$ is zero measure.

Hint: a $C^1$ function is lipchitz over a compact set.

What I did:

$E$ is of zero measure, so for all $\epsilon >0$ there are boxes $U_i$ such that $E \subseteq \cup_i U_i$ and $\sum_i V(U_i) \leq \epsilon$ (here V stands for volume in the sense of $\mathbb R^n$).

Let us define $m(A)$ as the measure of set $A$. It is clear to see that $f(E) \subseteq f(\cup_i U_i)$ and as such:

$m(f(E)) \leq m(f(\cup_i U_i))$

Now I assume that $f$ is lipchitz. and that means $m((f(\cup_i U_i)) \leq Km(\cup_i U_i)$

Because $m(\cup_i U_i) \leq \epsilon$ we get that $m(f(E)) \leq K\epsilon$ since $\epsilon$ can be as small as we like, I am tempted to say that $f(E)$ is of zero measure but i am not entirely sure.

But even if it is. I made the assumption that $f$ is lipchitz, but what if it isn't?

Comment: Your proof is good.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am very interested in fixing the hole I made in my proof when i said "lets assume $f$ is lipchitz" I lost generality.

Comment: Write your set as the countable union of compact sets. If you can show that the image of each has measure zero this will imply that the entire image has measure zero.

Comment: But why $m((f(\cup_i U_i)) \leq Km(\cup_i U_i)$ from the lipchitz condition of $f$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution to your problem: define
$$
E_n = E \cap [-k,k]\times \cdots \times [-k,k]
$$
Note that while $f$ might not be Lipschitz in general over $\Bbb R^n$, it is certainly Lipschitz over the compact "hyper-cube" $[-k,k]\times \cdots \times [-k,k]$, so that $f(E_k)$ is of measure zero.  Now, note that
$$
f(E) = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} f(E_k)
$$

Comment: Ah very well done!