# Can this proof be applied to C1-functions

Tags: lebesgue-measure

In [show that a straight line has a Lebesgue measure of zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310260/show-that-a-straight-line-has-a-lebesgue-measure-of-zero), does the proof given applies to every $C^1$-function or does it need some changes for it to be true?

More specifically, I want to know if
the argument that $λ(K)≤∑_i(b_i−a_i)\frac{2ϵ}{2^i}$ works for $f(x)$ as $C^1$-function?

Comment: If you rephrase this question, it will be upvoted more. Phrase it shortly outlining the proof, try to adapt the proof, maybe, and ask where it fails, if it does. At least share why you think what you do.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Tried to direct the question to the proof itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. I think the following works:

It is a general fact that if $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is a $C^1$ function, then the graph $$\Gamma(f):=\{(x,v) \mid f(x)=v\}$$
is a [$C^1$ submanifold of codimension $1$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245165/the-graph-of-a-smooth-real-function-is-a-submanifold). Indedd, the map $f:\mathbb R^n \to \Gamma(f)$, $x \mapsto (x,f(x))$ provides a $C^1$-diffeomorphism to the graph, [so it is enough to see that hyperplanes have measure zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765498/show-that-the-image-of-a-zero-measure-set-is-of-zero-measure), so the last proof applies.